# Android: SQLite DB trying to not overwrite values every time I start

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to figure out what order I need to do everything to have my program flow well and not crash.  I want the player of my game to have a team of three people each as their own class with stats such as attack, health, etc.

1. When the game is first installed and run, I want to have a sqlite db made and filled with the 3 starter characters.
2. When they start it any other time, I want to have the three stored characters in the DB to be assigned to 3 local character objects.

I have a SQLite Adapter class handling the Db but I'm not sure how to order everything so that I check first to see if there is a Db in the programs Db path and open it if there is.  Otherwise just create a new one and populate it with the initial characters.

I currently have:

```
DbAdapter = new PlayerDbAdapter(this);
    DbAdapter.open();
    DbAdapter.setInitialPlayers();    // inserts my initial player object info into the Db
```

which calls

```
public PlayerDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new SummonSQLiteHelper(context);
        String s = DbPath + DB_NAME;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(s, null);
        return this;
}
```

And now I'm a little lost as to what I need to make sure that I don't overwrite any saved info in the Db with the initial values everytime I start the program.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
public PlayerDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new SummonSQLiteHelper(context);
    String s = DbPath + DB_NAME;
    bool b=checkDataBase(s);
   if(b==false)
    {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(s, null);
        setInitialPlayers(); <---- set initial values here
     }
  else
  {
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(s, null);

  }
  return this;
   }
    private boolean checkDataBase(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
try {
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(str, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    checkDB.close();
} catch (SQLiteException e) {
    // database doesn't exist yet.
}
return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```